# How can I specify allowable word break locations for long words?

Tags: android, text

Let's say I want to add the word 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious' to a TextView. How can I specify at what points Android may break up the word when it wraps it across multiple lines?

As an example, I only want Android to break the word at the locations specified by a hyphen as follows:

```
su-per-cal-i-frag-il-is-tic-ex-pi-al-i-do-cious
```

In this case, Android might display the word as:

```
supercalifrag-
ilisticexpial-
idocious
```

Comment: Do that yourself via code? Put newline characters at your self assigned split points

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to automate it. Just as Android looks for spaces in a sentence to avoid splitting up words when wrapping, I want Android to look for predefined points in a word to decide where to split a word when wrapping. This would then account for different screen sizes and I wouldn't have to program the break points in each word multiple times (one for each screen layout and orientation).

Answer (score 3):

Soft Hyphen to the rescue! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen

First, you must set this property on a TextView:

> android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"

Then you use the Soft Hypen character inside your strings:

> &#173;

Like so:

> supercalifrag&#173;ilisticexpial&#173;idocious

Answer (score 1):

Extend `TextView` and implement this behavior - there is no in-build approach for that.